# Detect Online/Offline in Electron app for windows application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm working on React & Electron TS Application, I'm using the official docs for knowing if we have wifi or not. For mac is working as expected, but for **windows** the window.addEventListener("online") is not working, do you know any reason why ?

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/online-offline-events